# Instagram Tag API: Media_count does not match total media fetched

Tags: api, instagram

I call tag info request by `URL` and the result shows up in the media_count is 526. Here is my request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/ckdowntownau?client_id=add38d4ea81e4665962b939c96a929a3&count=526
```

However, when I fetch media using the `API`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/ckdowntownau/media/recent?client_id=add38d4ea81e4665962b939c96a929a3
```

I can get only 435 media.

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Comment: May be the count includes both private and public image tag count, and it only shows photos that are public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the media count number includes deleted photos. I verified this with a test.

Answer (score 2):

The Instagram API call /tags/{tag-name} returns:

```
{
    "data": {
        "media_count": 472,
        "name": "nofilter",
    }
}
```

The reason why you won't get a matching number when you fetch the actual images is because of privacy settings set by some users.

These images count when requesting tag info, but they won't be fetched when requesting images with /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent.

I tested this by requesting a media_count for an example hashtag with media_count at 0. Then set my privacy settings to private and uploaded a photo with that hashtag. media_count incremented, but media/recent returned nothing.